# Dynamic CheckBoxes in GridView Rows are not showing properly in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview in which i am showing values to be checked or unchecked in gridview rows checkboxes..Now i want to these values dynamically in gridview rows but its not going to happen ..All of the checkboxes are coming checked whereas result should be different ..

here is my hardcoded code condition to show the result which is coming  fine...

```
string[] rolesarr = Roles.GetAllRoles();

    DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
    dTable.Columns.Add("Select", typeof(bool));
    dTable.Columns.Add("Username", typeof(string));
    Array.ForEach(rolesarr, r => dTable.Columns.Add(r, typeof(bool)));
    foreach (MembershipUser u in Membership.GetAllUsers())
    {
        DataRow dRow = dTable.NewRow();
        dRow[0] = false;
        dRow[1] = u.UserName;
        string[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(u.UserName);
        dRow[2] = roles.Contains("Admin") ? true : false;
        dRow[3] = roles.Contains("DPAO User") ? true : false;
        dRow[4] = roles.Contains("GeneralUser") ? true : false;
        dTable.Rows.Add(dRow);
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = dTable;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Now i want to make this condition dynamic for which i have written code..

```
string[] rolesarr = Roles.GetAllRoles();

    DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
    dTable.Columns.Add("Select", typeof(bool));
    dTable.Columns.Add("Username", typeof(string));
    Array.ForEach(rolesarr, r => dTable.Columns.Add(r, typeof(bool)));
    foreach (MembershipUser u in Membership.GetAllUsers())
    {
        DataRow dRow = dTable.NewRow();
        dRow[0] = false;
        dRow[1] = u.UserName;
        string[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(u.UserName);

        for (int i = 0; i < roles.Length; i++)
        {

            string rol = roles[i];

            for (int j = 2; j < dTable.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                dRow[j] = roles.Contains(rol) ? true : false;

            }

        }
     dTable.Rows.Add(dRow);
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = dTable;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

And Here is my RowDatabound event for checkboxes ..

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound1(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        CheckBox c0 = (CheckBox)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
        CheckBox c2 = (CheckBox)e.Row.Cells[2].Controls[0];
        CheckBox c3 = (CheckBox)e.Row.Cells[3].Controls[0];
        CheckBox c4 = (CheckBox)e.Row.Cells[4].Controls[0];
        c0.Enabled = c2.Enabled = c3.Enabled = c4.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Please guys help me ..Thanks in advance...

Comment: Show your checkbox column of the grid, and also the columns that pertain to that checkbox column.

Comment: Sir Array.ForEach(rolesarr, r => dTable.Columns.Add(r, typeof(bool))); this line is adding column names dynamically in gridview

Answer (score 0):

the problem should be the double loops you provided.

According to your hardcoded code, you want to map between roles in the array `rolesarr` and `roles` of users, to show which roles is checked for each user.

To set values for data row at indext 2 - 4, you will have two loops, first loop to repeat  `rolesarr` array and second loop to repeat `roles` array and compare them in the second loop

This is the code I mean:

```
string[] rolesarr = Roles.GetAllRoles();

DataTable dTable = new DataTable();

dTable.Columns.Add("Select", typeof(bool));
dTable.Columns.Add("Username", typeof(string));
Array.ForEach(rolesarr, r => dTable.Columns.Add(r, typeof(bool)));
foreach (MembershipUser u in Membership.GetAllUsers())
{
    DataRow dRow = dTable.NewRow();
    dRow[0] = false;
    dRow[1] = u.UserName;
    string[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(u.UserName);

    for (int i = 0; i < rolesarr.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < roles.Length; j++)
        {
            if (rolesarr[i] == roles[j])
            {
                dRow[i + 2] = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    dTable.Rows.Add(dRow);
}
GridView1.DataSource = dTable;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Please notice that I use data row index as `i + 2` **(dRow[i + 2])** in the second loop, because your role columns start at index=2, not 0, and the length must equal `rolesarr.Length` which you use them as role colums.